# Bootstrap- Navbar toggle are not showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Navbar-toggle for showing group menus on mobile devices but it's not working! What is the problem? The Following is my code and JsFiddle.
Actually When I give class `navbar-toggle` the button disapear!

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav navbar-collapse collapsed" id="menu">
                    <li class="active" id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tel</a></li>
                </ul>
                <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
            </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #dedede;
}
.navbar-nav > li:first-child > a{
    background-color: #01a89e;
    color: white;
}
.navbar-nav > li:first-child a:hover, .navbar-nav > li:first-child a:active {
    background-color: #01a89e;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover{
    background-color: #dedede;
}
.navbar-nav{
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.navbar-nav li:not(:first-child){
   border-left: 1px solid #dedede;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
.navbar-nav li:hover{
    /*border: none;*/
}
.navbar-nav li a{
    color: #606060;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
#logo{
    width: 120px;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kc1xbmr3/)

Comment: navbar-default is missing class on nav Element, adding that shows up button and toggling as well, you can override default colors, Check out 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06odccmc/2/)

Comment: @JackRyder Thanks a lot but by default in mobile size the menu is not collapsed however I gave class `collapsed` to the `ul` tag. How can I fix that?

Comment: try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/06odccmc/3/), I put  ul into div and gave class "navbar-collapse collapse" to container, which will now keeping collapsed by default

Comment: @JackRyder Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @JackRyder said, `navbar-default` is missing class on `nav` Element, adding that shows up button and toggling as well. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06odccmc/2/)

Comment: `navbar-default`, `navbar-light`, or `navbar-dark` is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, fixed it by setting `navbar-dark` in  `<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">`